# R - Arrays with variable dimension

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a weird question..

Essentially, I have a function which takes a data frame of dimension Nx(2k) and transforms it into an array of dimension Nx2xk. I then further use that array in various locations in the function.

My issue is this, when k == 2, I'm left with a matrix of degree Nx2, and even worse, if N = 1, I'm stuck with a matrix of degree 1x2.

I would like to write `myArray[thisRow,,]` to select that slice of the array, but this falls short for the N = 1, k = 2 case. I tried `myArray[thisRow,,,drop = FALSE]` but that gives an 'incorrect number of dimensions' error. This same issue arrises for the Nx2 case.

Is there a work around for this issue, or do I need to break my code into cases?

Sample Code Shown Below:

```
thisFunction <- function(myDF)
{
    nGroups = NCOL(myDF)/2
    afMyArray = myDF        

    if(nGroups > 1)
    {
        afMyArray = abind(lapply(1:nGroups, function(g){myDF[,2*(g-1) + 1:2]}),
                          along = 3)
    }

    sapply(1:NROW(myDF), 
           function(r)
           {
               thisSlice = afMyArray[r,,]
               *some operation on thisSlice*
           })
}
```

Thanks,

James

Comment: Could you post the code of your function? It would help us answer your question if we could see what it looks like. Also, I'd recommend using * to represent multiplication, not "x", as it could be confused with a variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but `x<-array(0, dim=c(1,2,1)); x[1,,]` seems to be valid. (assuming you meant when `k==1`). Sounds like your reshape is just incorrect.

Comment: Can you control the input at all? Use `[... , drop = FALSE]` to keep a 1x2 matrix from being reduced to a vector.

Comment: @WillBeason, the * isn't denoting multiplication, it's defining the dimension of the matrix.

Also, sample code provided

Comment: I have figured out the issue. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @jameselmore For example, "array of dimension Nx2xk" would be clearer as "array of dimension N*2*k"

Comment: If you've solved your own question, you should post it as an answer to close out the post.